# How can I fix an incorrect result count with Sphinx and CakePHP pagination?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, sphinx

Sphinx search displays correct results but I'm running into a problem with pagination. If my search returns 3 records, it would say "Page 1 of 1, showing 15 records out of 15 total, starting on record 1, ending on 15". Say my keyword is "How", `app/views/posts/index.ctp` shows 3 records with the word "How" but my pagination shows "showing 15 records out of 15 total" instead of "showing 3 records out of 3 total."

I have these lines in my code:

```
$sphinx = array('matchMode' => SPH_MATCH_ALL, 'sortMode' => array(SPH_SORT_EXTENDED => '@relevance DESC')); 
    $results = $this->Post->find('all', array('search' => $this->data['Post']['query'], 'sphinx' => $sphinx)); 
    $this->set('posts', $results, $this->paginate());
```

How should I go about fixing the pagination so it will show the correct number of items found?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly you're not providing enough information for the community to understand where the problem resides...

I could suggest you try AJAX based pagination ([link1](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1234/AJAX-Pagination) , [link2](http://book.cakephp.org/1.3/view/1600/Ajax-Pagination)) and include the output of that in your sphinx output, but I do not know if you're experiencing problems connected (only) to Shpinx or Cake, or both?

Comment: Hi Borislav, thank you for the response. I think the problem resides on my cakephp. The code above is in my app/controllers/posts_controller.php and if i pass it onto my view, it displays the results ($results), however, the pagination always shows the total of all the posts in my database ("showing 15 records out of 15 total")instead of just the number of records found. Say, I my keyword is "How", app/views/posts/index.ctp shows 3 records with the word "How" but my pagination shows "showing 15 records out of 15 total" instead of "showing 3 records out of 3 total." Hope, this makes sense.

TY

Comment: Hi Lyman, this does make more sense.While searching you change the number of results. Pagination is used to display large quantities of data records in a "paginated" matter. When you're doing a search you're changing the result set, but not the pagination options. I suppose this is why you're experiencing this issue. Maybe if you change the pagination to count the search results and change the content of the pagination counters on the fly it would all work for you. This is actually just a suggestion, but I see no other way this could be done. Take a close look at the examples provided.

Comment: Custom Ajax based pagination is not the easiest thing to do, but it is an interesting feature of Cake. Feel free to ask more, so we can try to help. Cheers.